# Angular2 Directive - selector with multiple ids

Tags: angular, selector, directive, angular2-forms

I'm implementing a custom directive in Angular 2, directive for form validation, and in many places I see that in the directive definition the selector property is associated with multiple ids - for example:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[my-custom-validator][ngModel]'
})
```

What does the multiple '[...]' (brackets) selection mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in CSS, the selector `[attr]` matches elements that have an attribute named `attr`. When multiple attribute selectors are chained together, *all* the attributes must exist on the element.

**Note:** Unlike CSS, Angular ignores any `[...]` or `[(...)]` binding brackets on the target attribute when it performs the match.

Thus, the selector `[my-custom-validate][ngModel]` matches elements that have both a `my‑custom‑validate` attribute and an `ngModel` attribute (including `[ngModel]` and `[(ngModel)]`). For example, the selector matches

```
 <input type="text" name="username" my-custom-validate [(ngModel)]="model.username">
```

but not

```
 <input type="text" name="username" my-custom-validate>
```

Comment: So I guess we want to leverage the ngModel attribute and attach our directive only to components with ngModel? otherwise no change will occur?